# Prevent interpreting leading zero for number as octal

Tags: php, octal

JavaScript allows us to use `use strict` to prevent using octals with leading zero (throws an error, but better than using octal value without notifying)

How can we do the same with php? Can we set any global flag that will prevent PHP from interpreting leading zero as octal?

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: The same way you can't force php to not interpret numbers with a leading `0x` as hex you can't force php to not interpret numbers with a leading `0` as octal. The fact that `0123` is also a valid decimal number while `0x123` is not is a coincidence

Answer (score 1):

> Can we set any global flag that will prevent PHP from interpreting leading zero as octal?

No

> How can we do the same with php?

Own wrapper/filter, something like:

```
function getDecimalNumber(string $num): int 
{
    $decimalNum = filter_var($num, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
    if ($decimalNum === false) {
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException("The '$num' is not a decimal number.");
    }

    return $decimalNum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no global setting that I know of.  But you could strip leading zeroes.

```
$str = ltrim( $str, '0' );
```

Answer (score 0):

> To use octal notation, precede the number with a 0 (zero)

Straight from the PHP documentation. From that you can deduce that any integer leading with 0 will be considered as octal.

Check out: [PHP:Integers - Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php)